# z80 assembler issues with "IM 1" instruction

Tags: assembly, interrupt, z80

### Code

```
STACK .EQU 2099H
.ORG 0000H
    ld  SP, STACK
    jp 2000H

.ORG 0038H
    jp  service_routine

.ORG 2000H
    EI
    IM 1 ; <------- THIS LINE 
    LD  A, 00H

LOOP:
    ADD A, 00H
    jp  z, LOOP

service_routine:
    DI
    ld  A, 55H
    out (07H),A
    ld  A, 00H
    EI
    ret
```

### Error

Using this online IDE http://clrhome.org/asm/

It gives me:
**Unknown instruction or directive IM (line " IM 1" in hello_z80)**

### So?

Am i doing something stupid here?

I have no clue as to why i get this error.

Haven't had any luck with google.

Comment: Their assembler doesn't appear to to support that OP code. What do they say about it?

Comment: using another assembler and it works fine

Comment: I tried "IM1" (some assemblers accept only that form), but it didn't work either. I've let DeepThought know about it. In the meantime, you can `#define IM1 .db $ED, $56` and use `IM1` as a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I've let DeepThought know about it. I just hopped on the chat at Omnimaga (DeepThought is an admin there), and he told me he has fixed it.

`IM 0`, `IM 1` and `IM 2` all work now. They assemble and autocomplete knows about them too.

So in answer to your question, yes, it was in fact a bug and not your fault.